# Comment comprendre « juste le temps de gober du soleil » ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Je tente d’éplucher cette phrase, mais je n’y parviens pas.

> Il rentre le premier, juste le temps de gober du soleil

Elle fait (aussi) partie de la chanson *Planter des Cailloux* de Syrano.

Ce qui se trouve derrière la virgule est le morceau le plus épineux. J’ai essayé de trouver des renseignements sur la toile, mais je n’y ai pas reçu assez d’indices pour le déchiffrer.
Voici ce que j’ai trouvé :

- Apparemment, le mot « gober » veut dire « bouffer » ou « croire
  aveuglement ».
- J’ai de la peine à rapprocher les mots « juste le temps de » avec les
  autres composants de la phrase. Ces mots sont souvent accompagnés d'*avoir*, mais ce verbe n'est pas présent ici.
- Je dirais que « gober du soleil » veut dire « jouir de la lumière
  qu'il répand ». Mais pour faire cela, il vaut mieux *sortir*, alors
  que le sujet *rentre* dans ce qui était autrefois sa maison.

Pouvez vous m’apprendre ce que cette phrase veut dire ?

---

**Note**: Ceci est la deuxième question que je pose sur cette chanson. Je la comprends très mal parce qu’il y autant de langage imagé dans ces paroles. Avertissez-moi si vous pensez que ma question s’éloigne de la langue française, et que je devrais chercher une explication ailleurs.

Answer (score 3):

"gober du soleil", je le comprends effectivement comme *prendre un maximum de soleil* un peu comme on dit *croquer la vie à pleine dents* pour quelqu'un qui profite de la vie.

Mais il y a aussi une notion de vitesse, car gober c'est avaler d'un seul morceau (un poisson gobe la nourriture, voir vers précédant *il tourne en rond comme un poisson dans son bocal*).

Cela pourrait donc aller avec "juste le temps de ~": quand arrive l'heure de la promenade, il prend un rapide bol d'air frais et de soleil, ramasse un caillou, rentre le premier dans sa cellule de prison et s'évade par la pensé.